# Use barneygale/quarry with Microsoft Account

Tags: python, authentication, minecraft

My goal is to create a python script, that connects to a Minecraft server.
Apparently barneygale/quarry is a widely used library for this purpose.
My problem right now is, that I cant't find a way to use this library with an Microsoft Account. The Profile.from_credentials function apparently only works with Mojang accounts.
There is an other way to create a profile, using an access token and a client token.
I've found another library (msmcauth), which creates a new access token, but I can't figure out, were to get the client token.
Here is my code:

```
from quarry.net.auth import Profile
import msmcauth
    
loginDetails = msmcauth.login("email", "password")

profile = Profile.from_token("foo", loginDetails.access_token, loginDetails.uuid, loginDetails.username)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change the place of the arguments.
the order is:

```
profile = Profile.from_token("foo", loginDetails.access_token, loginDetails.username, loginDetails.uuid)
```

It works for me...