# Minecraft Quarry library 'Auth failed' error

Tags: python, proxy, minecraft, packet-sniffers

I am trying to make a Minecraft proxy(packet-sniffer) where I can intercept packets and thus change them, drop them or even create completely new packets. I am trying to accomplish this using the python quarry library which can be found [here](https://github.com/barneygale/quarry/tree/master?tab=readme-ov-file).

I tried testing a base proxy from this library which can be found [here](https://github.com/barneygale/quarry/blob/master/docs/networking/writing_proxies.rst).

Having only changed the listening port to 55555; the code is as follows:

```
from twisted.internet import reactor
from quarry.net.proxy import DownstreamFactory, Bridge


class ExampleBridge(Bridge):
    pass


def main(argv):
    factory = DownstreamFactory()
    factory.bridge_class = ExampleBridge
    factory.connect_host = "127.0.0.1"
    factory.connect_port = 25566
    factory.listen("127.0.0.1", 55555)
    reactor.run()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    main(sys.argv[1:])
```

Note that my Minecraft server (and client) are running on version 1.8.9. Furthermore, when trying to connect to the server from my client, I am using the serveradress: localhost:55555

When I run the code and join the server using my Minecraft client I get the following error in both my code and my Minecraft client:

```
Auth failed: [<twisted.python.failure.Failure OpenSSL.SSL.Error: [('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('system library', '', ''), ('STORE routines', '', 'unsupported'), ('SSL routines', '', 'certificate verify failed')]>]
```

I've heard people saying this error has something to do with OpenSSL not working correctly on a Windows device and I have other heard saying this has something to with Quarry trying to log in using your Mojang credentials while you can actually only sign in using your Microsoft credentials (which whould be a weard reason since nowhere in the code I specify any of my credentials).

Tho I do remember testing out a random GitHub repository I found which was based on Quarry. Here I did need to fill in my credentials, but I still got the same error. I can't find this repository anymore, so I can't pin it here.

Lastly I have gotten a proxy working one time using [this](https://github.com/TheStaticTurtle/MineProxy) GitHub repository. I was able to join my server while online_mode was turned on. This code however is far to comprehensive and 'huge' for me to understand everything. Furhtermore I was't able to find where the packets got processed, so I couldn't intercept any packets.

Last Lastly I've read something about msmcauth on [another StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72408417/use-barneygale-quarry-with-microsoft-account). Maby this is a valid solution, but I couldn't get it working.